# Debugging PHP in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to debug a wamp-based website using VSC. When I start the debugger using the configuration Listen for XDebug, the Debug control panel opens.  The Step Over, Step Into and Step Out controls are not active (I assume they become active when the program starts?).  I have two breakpoints set up.
This is the launch.json file that VSC created for PHP:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
```

This is the XDebug config in php.ini

```
; XDEBUG Extension
[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.31/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.5.5-5.6-
vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

I changed these lines as per XDebug extension docs in VSC

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

When I start(submit a form), the code executes, but the VSC debugger doesn't engage, execution doesn't stop at the breakpoints, data is inserted in some tables.  Am I missing some configuration so that the debugger does something, stops at the breakpoints?  The VSC docs here 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging
only highlight debugging with Node.js debugger.  Appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: You are using the PHP Debug extension - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug - there are lots of troubleshooting tips in the readme, you'll want to start there.

Comment: I had a look at that webpage, didn't see a readme link.  Is it called readme or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to ask for more info through comment section but I did not have enough reputation to do so :)

I suspect the `PHP.ini` file that you have modified is not the correct one. As you mentioned, you're dealing with WAMP, therefore there must be at least two `PHP.ini` files:

- Command Line Interface (CLI)
- Apache.

You should have modified the second one since you're running Apache.

I'm not quite sure about the exact path to those two files. I hope this could help.

*How to know which `PHP.ini` is loaded?*

*Run `phpinfo();` in your script in VSCode. It brings up your PHP configuration info. Look for: **Loaded Configuration File***.